# @PreRemove not being fired on child entity on CASCADE parent deletion

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

i'm currently working on a Springboot project, and i'm facing a problem: 
I want to fire a method before each **Child** is deleted, and my code is below.

I have a **Parent** class and a **Child** one following this configuration:

```
@Entity
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private List<Child> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
public class Child implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "child_id", nullable = false)
    @Getter(onMethod = @__({@JsonIgnore}))
    private Parent parent;

    @PreRemove
    void test() {
        System.out.println("Before removing");
    }
}
```

**What I want:**
When a **Parent** object is deleted, the Anottation `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` will be fired and every Child object related will be deleted too, but I want do some logic before it happens.

**What is happening:**
When a **Parent** object is deleted, the Anottation `@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)` is fired and every Child object related isdeleted but the method with @PreRemove is not being fired.

Do I need to add more configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are issues with the mapping .You need to create a separate eventlistener class and mention the event listener class name on the child entity (You can create a static class in the entity itself as well).
Also in parent entity you need to have option to cascade.ALL

```
@Entity
@Table(name="PARENT")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    List<Child> childList=new ArrayList<>();


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addChild(Child child)
    {
        child.setParent(this);
        childList.add(child);
    }
}
```

Child Entity with the event listener annotation on class level

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CHILD")
@EntityListeners(ChildEntityListener.class)
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(name="NAME")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
    Parent parent;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Parent getParent() {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

The event listener class

```
public class ChildEntityListener {

    @PreRemove
    void test(Child child) {
        System.out.println("Before removing Child Entity");
    }
}
```

The calling code for it

```
public void entityListener() {
    Parent parent = new Parent();
    parent.setName("Test Parent");

    Child child = new Child();
    child.setName("Test Child");
    parent.addChild(child);

    Child child1 = new Child();
    child1.setName("Test Child 2");
    parent.addChild(child1);

    parentRepo.save(parent);


    List<Parent> parentList = parentRepo.findAll();
    for (Parent p : parentList) {
        parentRepo.delete(p);

    }

}
```

More information can be found here [enter link description here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#events-jpa-callbacks-example)

Note :- As mentioned in the comment creating and adding the EventListener class and placing the annotation on child entity is optional.

Comment: Thanks! Just adding `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` made `@PreRemove` to be triggered! It was not necessary to create a EventListener, but it is useful for more complex stuff I guess. Thanks again!